# bokeh line graph for 3 lines

Tags: python, pandas, graph, bokeh

I have a data of various year and months want to display in 3 lines graph based on category and X axis will be (jan,feb.......dec) Y axis sales. I am confused how to do this as I am new to Bokeh and Python can someone help me please?

```py
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from datetime import datetime
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral3

output_file('output.html')

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
p = figure(x_axis_type="date")
p.line(x=df.date, y=df.sales, line_width=2)

show(p)
```

This is the data I have.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the contents of the Dates column to Dates. Pandas and Bokeh don't know that these values are dates and treat them like strings if you forget to do this. Also, the x_axis_type should be datetime instead of date.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral3

data = {'Date': ['08-11-2016', '08-11-2016', '12-06-2016', '11-08-2015', '11-10-2015', '09-06-2014', '09-02-2014', '09-01-2014', '09-06-2014', '09-03-2014', '09-05-2014', '09-07-2014', '15-04-2017', '05-12-2016', '22-09-2015', '26-12-2015', '02-01-2015', '02-01-2015', '28-10-2016'],
'Sales': [261.96, 731.94, 14.62,957.5775, 22.368, 48.68, 7.28, 907.152, 18.504, 114.9, 1706.184, 911.424, 15.552, 407.976, 68.81, 2.544, 665.88, 55.5, 8.56],
'Category': ['Furniture', 'Furniture', 'Office Supplies', 'Furniture', 'Office Supplies', 'Furniture', 'Office Supplies', 'Technology', 'Office Supplies', 'Office Supplies', 'Furniture', 'Technology', 'Office Supplies', 'Office Supplies', 'Office Supplies', 'Office Supplies', 'Office Supplies', 'Office Supplies', 'Office Supplies']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(by='Date')
categories = df['Category'].unique()

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime")
for cat, color in zip(categories, Spectral3):
    df_line = df.loc[df['Category'] == cat]    
    p.line(x='Date', y='Sales', line_width=2, source=df_line, legend=cat, color=color)
p.legend.click_policy="hide"
show(p)
```

[image]

(Technology and Office supplies are also plotted, its just difficult to see them due to the short x range/color)

Comment: I tried this with my data but the lines are not getting plotted properly

Comment: ``` OrderDate         Category        Sales
0        2014        Furniture   82832.5164
1        2014  Office Supplies   86661.4220
2        2014       Technology  109617.4640
3        2015        Furniture   84801.7080
4        2015  Office Supplies   63019.8670
5        2015       Technology   82248.2500
6        2016        Furniture   85607.4175
7        2016  Office Supplies   82121.6480
8        2016       Technology   96572.8750
9        2017        Furniture  100269.3538
10       2017  Office Supplies  125699.4660
11       2017       Technology  140890.0350

Comment: Maybe because your Date column is now called OrderDate? I can only speculate as long as you don't upload (a part of) your data somewhere and add it to your question.